# Kill a process in remote linux machine using batch file

Tags: linux, unix, networking, grep, kill

I am new to this field and i need to kill a process running in my remote linux machine
I have started a nmon process using a batch file.... This batch file contains START PUTTY command which invokes a .sh file in the remote and start nmon...

Now i need to kill that process using a batch file. I tried using kill pgrep nmon..... But when i execute that batch file it is showing "Network error. Couldnt connect to specified address"

Is there any way to kill that process using a batch file that uses putty from my windows machine???

Comment: Please post your files, what you've tried and the errors you get.

Comment: MY BATCH FILE
start putty.exe -ssh UserName@Machine -pw PASSWORD -m samples.txt

Answer (score 0):

Instructions to execute a remote instruction using SSH connection from Windows with non-interactive shell using credentials:

1. Create a text file with list of commands to be executed. (Examaple: create a file `C:\remote_commands.txt` with the command `pkill process-name` inside)
2. Execute from CLI or create a batch with a line like this: `C:\PATH\putty.exe -ssh USER@IP-ADDRESS -pw PASSWORD -m C:\remote_commands.txt`

Some commands may require an user with administrative privileges, be carefull with this point.

That's all, try and enjoy!

There are similar questions at:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116672/running-linux-script-on-remote-linux-system-using-putty